# Received unexpected message type does not match expected type Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I am new to Biztalk, I have consumed a WCF service and created my own schema and orchestration.
Then published the WCF service, all things went well , but when I am running the published service from SOAP UI I am getting this exception in Biztalk server administrator

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'BizTalkEmployeeInfo.BizTalk_Orchestration1(8e85552e-b611-e6a6-655f-b3b58002a88d)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
>   If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: eb2b7522-db03-40f0-9cfa-28509fea03b0
>   Shape name: 
>   ShapeId: 
>   Exception thrown from: segment -1, progress -1
>   Inner exception: Received unexpected message type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#Fault' does not match expected type 'http://tempuri.org/#EmployeeDetailsFormattedResponse'.
>
> Exception type: UnexpectedMessageTypeException
>   Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
>   Target Site: Void VerifyMessage(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Envelope, System.String, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.OperationInfo)
>   The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured  at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBinding.VerifyMessage(Envelope env, String typeName, Context cxt, OperationInfo op)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBinding.VerifyMessage(Envelope env, String typeName, Context cxt, OperationInfo op)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXLogicalPortBinding.VerifyMessage(Envelope env, String typeName, Context cxt, OperationInfo op)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.VerifyTransport(Envelope env, Int32 operationId, Context ctx)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Subscription.Receive(Segment s, Context ctx, Envelope& env, Boolean topOnly)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBase.GetMessageId(Subscription subscription, Segment currentSegment, Context cxt, Envelope& env, CachedObject location)
>      at BizTalkEmployeeInfo.BizTalk_Orchestration1.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)

Can someone help please here.

Comment: As Sanoraya has said you are getting a fault message from the service you are calling.  You do need to code for it (to handle occasional exceptions/outage), but if you are getting it all the time then you are obviously not calling the service correctly. However you have not provided us with any information that would help us diagnose what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your web service throws an exception - that is a message of the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/#Fault type, but BizTalk messaging/orchestration engine has no idea what to do with it. You need to configure your send port and orchestration to deal with the soap exceptions. See here for more details: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2013/02/12/how-to-handle-fault-message-in-biztalk-server/

Answer (score 0):

A very handy way to debug these is to use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). In your send port set fiddler to be the proxy. The communication from biztalk goes through, and is logged by, fiddler when it acts as a proxy. You can easily view the response that the BizTalk failure is hiding.